# How to remove array element if one key match?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically its dataSource for kendo grid default data is selVal ,If any key from selval is matching with dtoVal i want to delete everything 
from selVa, is it possible implement with below code its not deleting selVal elements from array. Any idea ?

ctrl.js

```
$scope.handleControlOwnerCancel = function(){
                this.ctrlOwnerModal.close();
                var dtoVal = $scope.controlDTO.controlOwners;
                var selVal = $scope.selectedOwners;
                for (var i = 0; i < dtoVal.length; i++) {
                  for (var j=0; j<selVal.length; j++)  {
                   if (dtoVal[i].workerKey  !== selVal[j].workerKey) {
                     $scope.selectedOwners = $scope.controlDTO.controlOwners;
                     controlOwnersDataSource();
                    }
                  }
                }

            };
```

Comment: When you say to delete everything from selVal, do you mean everything (empty the array) or just the stuff that matches dtoVal?

Comment: I want to empty `$scope.selectedOwners` array and set  `$scope.controlDTO.controlOwners` as new value to `$scope.selectedOwners`

Comment: $scope.selectedOwners = [];   ?

Comment: that will set it to empty i also want to set new value `$scope.controlDTO.controlOwners`

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to use `angular.forEach` instead of using `for` loop. Also you said

> If any key from selval is matching with dtoVal i want to delete
>   everything from selVa

But inside the loop you are checking with `!==`. I don't know which one is exactly your requirement. But you can try doing this:

```
$scope.handleControlOwnerCancel = function(){
    this.ctrlOwnerModal.close();
    //var dtoVal = $scope.controlDTO.controlOwners;
    //var selVal = $scope.selectedOwners;
    var match = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.selectedOwners, function(val, key){
        angular.forEach($scope.controlDTO.controlOwners, function(val2, key2){
            if(val.workerKey==val2.workerKey){
                match++;
            }
        })          
    })
    if(match>0){
        $scope.selectedOwners = $scope.controlDTO.controlOwners;
        controlOwnersDataSource();
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes if values are matching then i want to make condition true, thanks for the response your answer works first time but when i add more users and click on cancel instead of Save it still showing data from `$scope.selectedOwners` on top of `$scope.controlDTO.controlOwners` dont know what exactly happening here

Comment: I don't know what is going on outside this area of code so it is confusing. Let us know if/when you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$scope.handleControlOwnerCancel = function(){
  this.ctrlOwnerModal.close();
  var dtoVal = $scope.controlDTO.controlOwners;
  var selVal = $scope.selectedOwners;
  var selValCopy = angular.copy(selVal);
  for (var i=dtoVal.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    for (var j=selVal.length-1; j>=0; j--)  {
      if (dtoVal[i].workerKey  === selVal[j].workerKey) {
        selValCopy.splice(j, 1);
      } else {
        $scope.selectedOwners = $scope.controlDTO.controlOwners;
        controlOwnersDataSource();
      }
    }
  }
  selVal  = selValCopy;
};
```

Comment: Inverse array to improve performance, because no need to get the length every time